# Spinner popup dialog not adjusting its width on screen rotation

Tags: android, spinner, screen-orientation

I am using a `Spinner` with `android:spinnerMode="dropdown"`. I have also set `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` to prevent my `Activity` to get recreated. when I am in `Landscape` mode and click on `Spinner` it pops below the `Spinner` and have the width same as `Spinner` button, now when I rotate the screen to portrait mode the `Spinner` button width get reduced according to the screen size but the pop up dialog does not reduce its width accordingly.

Portrait mode screen:
[image]

LAndscape Mode Screen
[image]

I thought of closing the pop up and reopen it on screen orientation but I didn't found any way to close the pop up dialog.

Comment: can you start your app in landscape mode and see if the spinner has the width same as Spinner button. if true you have to invalidate the spinner to redraw. Why you are handling the screen rotation your self?

Comment: When do I call invalidate method on Spinner? can u explain in details..

Comment: Have you tried calling spinner.requestLayout() on the onConfigurationChanged() method?

Comment: @renam.antunes it also doesn't seems working for me..

Answer (score 2):

On the `onConfigurationChanged()` method call to `spinner.invalidate();`

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well. I ended up calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the spinnerAdapter in `onConfigurationChanged()` and it worked.